# How to get data (rows) from AWS RDS MySQL database instance with AWS SDK for .NET?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I can see the API reference, but it doesn't really tell me anything. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html

No example codes at all. I would like to read the content from an RDS db MySQL instance, and I would like to know every method for this thing to get work in C#. I can only find configuration examples, example codes only for Java and Ruby, and that's all. 
I heard it can be used with MySQL API, but that would not secure. I heard the SDK uses Cognito, which is way safer.

Based on [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/RDS/NRDS.html) I know the AWS SDK for .NET contains the RDS namespace.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Using_the_Query_API.html

This page tells me about some parameters, they're not defined at all. It's so general, I can't use that for anything.

I don't even know if I should use this query api page or not for this task.

There's also a [developer guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/aws-sdk-net-v3-dg.pdf) for AWS SDK for .NET, but this also doesn't contain any information about managing the RDS.

I could find [this](https://aws.amazon.com/code/c-library-for-amazon-rds/), but it says it is deprecated and will no longer updated. Also it seems it's not even uses the SDK for .NET.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/Index.html

Comment: @RodrigoM That doesn't contain any information at all. No example codes. How should I find out how to use this API? No attack, but have you even checked the link before writing that to me?

Comment: @RodrigoM I have extended the question.

Comment: Did you notice there are sample applications you can download? https://aws.amazon.com/developers/getting-started/net/

Comment: @Crowcoder The example is about creating a snapshot from a db instance identifier list and restoring it. Unfortunately I can't get the data tables from that snapshot.
At this point I'm not even sure if the API gives me possibility to get datas from a data table....

Comment: You don't use the AWS SDK to access data in MySQL. You would use a MySQL driver for .NET to connect and run queries against MySQL, just like you would for a MySQL database running anywhere else. You would use the AWS SDK to manage the server, not query the tables.

Comment: @MarkB Okay, good to know. Anyway, I don't understand why people gives -1 for my question. It's totally clear and very detailed, contains research... Way far from a bad question at all, and everybody can see that.

Comment: Other thing: Then what are the query strings for?

Comment: @greyline the "query" strings are for querying the AWS API. One of the examples given is to query for a list of your RDS instances. Don't assume the word "query" implies "SQL query", because it doesn't.

Comment: @MarkB I thought this SDK is for query tables, because it can query tables for DynamoDB. 
Then I would need to use AWS Lambda to create a safe API for the RDS db.

Comment: DynamoDB is a serverless, proprietary Amazon production. It makes sense that they would add full support for it in the AWS API/SDK. That's not the case for MySQL.

Comment: @MarkB please post your comment beginning with "You don't use the AWS SDK to access data in MySQL." to the Answer section, I will accept that as an answer. 
I hope I will get out from the question ban.... I still can't see why people downvote this question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm simply restating MarkB's comment as an answer, so that it can be accepted:

> You don't use the AWS SDK to access data in MySQL. You would use a MySQL driver for .NET to connect and run queries against MySQL, just like you would for a MySQL database running anywhere else. You would use the AWS SDK to manage the server, not query the tables.